# Digital Mixing Of Audio File

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-recording

I want to perform Digital Mixing of two audio files. I have used MixerHost- Apple's sample code for that. But I am unable to store mixed audio file on disk. Please guide me if anyone knows how to do that.
I have tried the answers posted on same questions asked by somebody else but that will be recording only some part of audio as much as I play,but I want mixed audio of both the file. How can I write that file on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an IO unit to the mixer and then write the audio data to a file using Extended Audio File Services on the new IO unit's callback function. You'll need to use `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync` to write the packets.

Check out the reference here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I am new to audio tool framework. How to add iounit to mixer? I am writing my file on callback function.

Comment: @spaleja Analyze the code in MixerHost and try to understand how and audio unit is added to the AUGraph. You can add an io audio unit the same way. It is little tough for beginners and will take some time to understand but there is no other way.

Comment: As much as I understood,mixerUnit is added to processingGraph. So you mean to say, I have to add ioUnit to processingGraph and write that file on disk?

Comment: @spaleja yes, you are right. You should add an io unit to the processing graph and then connect an output of the mixer unit to the io unit and then add a render callback for the io unit, where you write the packets to the file.

Comment: ohh, I was thinking, I'll get mixed audio file from mixerUnit as MixerUnitDescription having componentType 'kAudioUnitType_Mixer'(An audio unit that takes some number of inputs, mixing them to provide 1 or more audio outputs) and that is what I want.

Comment: @spaleja You'll have to write the audio packets yourself into a file.

Comment: Okie, do you have any refernce link for that? So that I can understand what exactly, I have to do it.

Comment: @spaleja http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ExtAudioFileWriteAsync

Consider marking as answer.

Comment: will this be helpful to me? http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Comment: @spaleja That could helpful too. In that case you'll have to write to the file using the buffer in the `DoStuffWithTheRecordedAudio` method. Nice blog!

Comment: I have achieved with file writing, but output file is not having different volume for different audio. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at https://docs.audiostack.ai/docs/automixingservice which allows you an AI-enabled mixing engine and an API!